# Использование TransactionScope

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, sql-server

Если блоком TransactionScope будет обрамлено N блоков соединений(После выполнения запроса соединение закрывается, а где-то в коде потом открывается новое) с выполнением запросов, то все эти соединения будут выполняться в рамках одной транзакции?
Иначе говоря, если в одном из N соединений вылетит ошибка, то откат в блоке catch откатит все изменения, которые были в предыдущих соединениях?

Будет ли работать откат, если соединения идут к разным серверам в рамках одного TransactionScope?

Т.е будет ли откат на другом сервере, если ошибка произойет в соединении другого сервера и я вызову rollback или при переходе на другой сервер будет автоматический commit?

Comment: Похоже на правду, для этого TransactionScope и существует. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22512547/276994

Comment: Именно так, откроется Distributed Transaction (распределенная транзакция). Для неё требуется допольнительная настройка серверов (собственно, надо будет устанавливать Distributed Transaction Manager и пр.)